# How to recognize characters in International Phonetic Alphabet when OCR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, cloud-document-ai

When doing the OCR of a dictionary pdf using DocumentAI, some IPA characters are often included, i.e. `ʷ` `ə` etc. Is there a way to recognize them correctly, such as setting a certain language hint? Currently `ʷ` is recognized as `w` and `ə` as `a`.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document AI only detects IPA characters that are in a [supported language](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/languages).

However, this could be a useful feature, so I made a Public Issue Tracker for this feature request. https://issuetracker.google.com/287464641